# How can I get the type of a class without instantiating it in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

Given an object it is easy to get the object type in python:

```
obj = SomeClass()
t = type(obj)
```

How can I do this without first creating an instance of the class?

Background: Once you have the type you easily can create instances of that type. Using this mechanism I want to pass a type to an object which will later create instances of that type. It would be very reasonable not to have to create an object first which will immediately be thrown away again.

Comment: `t = SomeClass`

Comment: The type of an object is the same as the class that created it.  Therefore, the type of a `SomeClass` object is `SomeClass`.  In Python 2, objects from old style classes are of type `instance`, but that isn't true in Python 3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See this example code:

```
class MyClass(object):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    o1 = MyClass()
    c = MyClass
    o2 = c()

    print(type(o1), type(o2), MyClass)
```

Defining a class binds it to its name (here: `MyClass`), which is nothing else but a reference to that definition. In this example, issuing `c = MyClass` just mirrors the class reference to another variable, the contents of the variables `c` and `MyClass` now are exactly the same. Thus, you can instantiate objects of that class by calling either of them (i.e. `MyClass()` or `c()`), resulting in the same effect.

Furthermore, testing for the type of an instantiated object results in the exact same class reference. You can even go one step further and do:

```
o3 = type(o1)()
```

Which creates a new instance of the class of which `o1` is.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that in more detail!

Answer (score 3):

This answer is for anyone who comes to this page wondering, "how can I *check* the type of a class without instantiating it in Python?"

If you are working with a variable that contains a class, rather than an object, you can check whether it is a certain class using the `issubclass()` built-in function.

Building off the previous answer:

```
>>> class MyClass(object):
...     pass
...
>>> c = MyClass
>>> type(c)
<class 'type'>
>>> issubclass(c, MyClass)
True
```